# How to update progressbar periodically in the background while switching between activities in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I have an Android application with 2 pages, which periodically switches every 10 secs. One of the page has a progressbar which needs to update every 2 secs. I am able to get till this part working. The issue I'm having is, the progressbar is resetting to  0% after every switch. How can I be able to update the progressbar continuously all the way to 100% without any interruption?

Here's my source code

**frame_2_activity.java**

```
package com.ossus.SC20.sub_screens;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import com.ossus.SC20.R;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class frame_2_activity extends Activity {

    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private TextView mLoadingText;



    private int mProgressStatus = 0;


    Handler handler = new Handler();


    Timer timer;

    private View _bg__frame_2;
    private ImageView background_1;
    private TextView text_view_date;
    private ImageView logo_2_1;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.frame_2_new);

        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        mLoadingText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LoadingCompleteTextView);


        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                startProgress();
            }
        });
        thread.start();


        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run(){
                Intent intent = new Intent(frame_2_activity.this, frame_3_activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }, 10000);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(calendar.getTime());

        TextView textViewDate = findViewById(R.id.text_view_date);
        textViewDate.setText(currentDate);


        _bg__frame_2 = (View) findViewById(R.id._bg__frame_2);
        background_1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background_1);
        text_view_date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_date);
        logo_2_1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo_2_1);



    }


      public void startProgress(){

        for (mProgressStatus = 0; mProgressStatus < 100; mProgressStatus = mProgressStatus + 1){

            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                mProgressBar.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mLoadingText.setText(String.valueOf(mProgressStatus + "% Completed"));
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

**frame_3_activity.java**

```
package com.ossus.SC20.sub_screens;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.ossus.SC20.MyExceptionHandler;
import com.ossus.SC20.R;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class frame_3_activity extends Activity {

    Timer timer;

    private View _bg__frame_3_ek2;
    private ImageView background_1;
    private ImageView logo_2_1;
    private TextView text_view_date;

    private TextView rxStatus;

    DatabaseReference dref;
    String value;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.frame_3);


        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyExceptionHandler(this));

        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("crash", false)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "App restarted after crash", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run(){
                Intent intent = new Intent(frame_3_activity.this, frame_6_activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }, 10000);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(calendar.getTime());

        TextView textViewDate = findViewById(R.id.text_view_date);
        textViewDate.setText(currentDate);


        _bg__frame_3_ek2 = (View) findViewById(R.id._bg__frame_3_ek2);
        background_1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background_1);
        logo_2_1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo_2_1);
        text_view_date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_date);
        rxStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rxStatusData);

        dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        dref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                value = snapshot.child("StatusOfTheRx").getValue().toString();
                rxStatus.setText(value);
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });


    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.ossus.SC20">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.SC20"
    tools:targetApi="31">


    <activity
        android:name=".sub_screens.frame_3_activity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:exported="true"  >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".sub_screens.frame_2_activity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:exported="true"  >
    </activity>

        <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />


</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

use a [forground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) store count in a [room database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) so the activity would retrieve the correct count.